# Sublime text auto-rename-tag

Tags: sublimetext3

Does anyone know how to find an auto-rename-tag package for Sublime Text? As you may be aware, Visual Studio Code has this feature, but Sublime Text lacks auto-rename-tag functionality. Can you recommend another package with similar capabilities?

I attempted to find a package but i can not find.